# Modify the state from another file in React

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have an `Index.js`, a `Buttons.js` and `Display.js`

Both `Buttons` and `Display` are imported to `Index`.
How can I change a state within `Display` by pressing a button in `Buttons.js`? Each different button in `Buttons.js` should display a different string.

Comment: There are several ways to handle this; one option is to use a state management library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: @Hamms Redux! Why didn't I think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the most basic example of what you actually want ....

this is the most basic way .

Display.js

```js
class Display extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Display Component</h3>
        <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Buttons.js

```js
class Buttons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.handler}>{this.props.buttonName }</button>
        {/* <button onClick={this.props.handlerB}> Button B </button> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js (I imported above files in App.js and then rendered App.js in index.js)

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = { displayState: "This is display state" };
  handlerForA = () => {
    this.setState({ displayState: "Changes by Handler A" });
  };
  handlerForB = () => {
    this.setState({ displayState: "Changes by Handler B" });
  };

  Reset = () => {
    this.setState({ displayState: "This is display state" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Display>{this.state.displayState}</Display>
        <br />
        <Buttons
          handler={() => {
            this.handlerForA();
          }}
          buttonName={"Button A"}
        />
        <br />
        <Buttons
          handler={() => {
            this.handlerForB();
          }}
          buttonName={"Button B"}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Buttons
          handler={() => {
            this.Reset();
          }}
          buttonName={"Reset"}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

basic structure of Display and Buttons are at their respective files and all state management at App file

[output of above code](https://17kk2.csb.app/)

[whole source code of above Application](https://codesandbox.io/s/statte-management-17kk2)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer for you is understanding what the state does.  you will have a state in one component and you will do anything you want with the state and you will pass it to props to other components so that the action triggered my that component will affect the other components because react can detect a change in state which will make your page re-render.. and display whatever you want. So in your specific case, You are trying to communicate to siblings of components(Button, Display) from their parent components(Index). React doesn't work like that. state that will affect both the components needs to be initialized in the parent components. So you need to lift up your state and initialize your state in index components and simply attach the state as props to the button and display components so that whenever the button is clicked it will trigger the state that is in the index component which makes your display component re-render and displays whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Have `display` take arguments by passing `props` into `display`. Alternatively, you could have a fourth component where `button.js` and `display.js` live and just import that into `index.js`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand what you're saying, but I might need a bit more hand holding on this one (still learning react)

Comment: @VictorLazaro then you probably want a tutorial, see e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html. SO isn't here for hand-holding.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I totally understand.